# How to Launch multiple browsers in TOSCA?

Tags: tosca

I am new to TOSCA, kindly guide me How to Launching multiple browsers in TOSCA?

Thanks in advance. 
Sreeni

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to what Kapil said above (which was about using browsers), here is how you can actually "launch" (=start) browsers.

Tosca treats browsers like any other application - you can start a browser using the `TBox Start Program` module (that you can get access to by importing the standard subset).

Tosca's manual actually provides an example of how to start Internet Explorer using that module, it works in a similar fashion with the other browsers. Here is a screenshot:

[image: TBox Start Program to launch Internet Explorer]

For the sake of completeness, here's the link to the manual for more details: https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=10.0.0&url=ep_tbox/process_operations/process_operations.htm

Answer (score 2):

We cannot trigger multiple browsers in TOSCA, but it supports cross browser execution. For cross browser execution:
1. Create a Test Configuration Parameter "Browser" either at TestCase or at its parent levels.
2. We can choose value InternetExplorer, Firefox, or Chrome.
3. The execution will be triggered on respective browser.

In order to achieve parallel execution we have to go with Distributed Execution (DEX).